# MySQL: Select within a Select within a View?

Tags: mysql, join, view

I'm trying to rebuild a *View* for my database, this is for a hockey statistics application I am building.

My situation is this: I am recording data for scoring plays, each `IndividualScoreHockey` has a  `TeamId` and `GameId`. With this data, I can take it over to the `MatchFixture` table and use the `GameId` to figure out which two teams are playing in the game.

So within my view of the `AllScoringPlays`, I want to create a column titled `OpponentId` which would give me the `TeamId` of the team that the `Goal` was against. So I believe I need to query the `MatchFixture` table using the `TeamId` from `IndividualScoreHockey` and compare where the `HomeTeamId` or the `AwayTeamId` doesn't equal the `TeamId` from `IndividualScoreHockey` and the `GameId` (ISH) equals the `Id` (MF)

I'm unsure of how to create a subquery which would execute this, I believe it would be something along the lines of:

`SELECT (HomeTeamId OR AwayTeamId) AS OpponentId FROM MatchFixture WHERE Id = foo AND (HomeTeamId != bar OR AwayTeamId != bar)`

Right now, my view looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW `AllScoringPlays` AS
SELECT 
    `ISH`.`GameId` AS `GameId`,
    `ISH`.`TeamId` AS `TeamId`,
    `MF`.`SeasonId` AS `SeasonId`,
    `ISH`.`Goal` AS `GoalId`,
    `ISH`.`P_Assist` AS `P_AssistId`,
    `ISH`.`S_Assist` AS `S_AssistId`,
    `ISH`.`Time` AS `Time`,
FROM
    (((((`IndividualScoreHockey` `ISH`
    join `User` `UG` ON ((`ISH`.`Goal` = `UG`.`Id`)))
    join `Team` `T` ON ((`T`.`Id` = `ISH`.`TeamId`)))
    join `MatchFixture` `MF` ON ((`ISH`.`GameId` = `MF`.`Id`)))
    left join `User` `UPA` ON ((`ISH`.`P_Assist` = `UPA`.`Id`)))
    left join `User` `USA` ON ((`ISH`.`S_Assist` = `USA`.`Id`)))
ORDER BY `ISH`.`Period` , `ISH`.`Time`
```

Here is a rough diagram of the data I have to work with

`MatchFixture`:

### ID | SeasonId | LeagueId | HomeTeamId | AwayTeamId | Date

`IndividualScoreHockey`:

### Id | TeamId | GameId | Goal | P_Assist | S_Assist | Time

(`Goal`, `P_Assist`, and `S_Assist` columns are the id's of players attributed to that scoring play)

I'm really new to views, so I am unsure of where to perform this subquery. Or maybe I can get away with a join, I'm not sure. Any help would be much appreciated. If I butchered anything here, please feel free to comment and I can try to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your query correcty, you can find the `OpponentId` you want either as `HomeTeamId` or as `AwayTeamId` in the `MatchFixture` record that you already join as `MF`. Then you.can obtain the result you want simply by adding this to the list of fields you select:

```
CASE WHEN MF.HomeTeamId = ISH.TeamId THEN MF.AwayTeamId ELSE MF.HomeTeamId
END AS OpponentId
```